# How to disable DEBUG message Selenium 4.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I have been trying to disable DEBUG message to console, but no matter what I do, it still display on the console . I need to find a way to disable the constant logging of the HTTP request and response on the console . Code used :

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 

   chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    // options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
    options.addArguments("--disable-logging");
    options.addArguments("--log-level=3");
    options.addArguments("--silent");
    options.setCapability( "goog:loggingPrefs", logPrefs );
    options.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    System.out.println("Launching Google Chrome Browser");
    //ChromeDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    //   options.merge(cap);



   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

on console

```
Request DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /session HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: selenium/4.0.0 (java windows)
Content-Length: 1259
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
host: localhost:61670
accept: */*

Response DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 788

[AsyncHttpClient-1-2] DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.ChannelManager - Adding key: http://localhost:61670 for channel [id: 0xaa9e94af, L:/127.0.0.1:63133 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:61670]
[AsyncHttpClient-1-3] DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener - Using new Channel '[id: 0x60845110, L:/127.0.0.1:63145 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:63134]' for 'GET' to '/json/version'
 [AsyncHttpClient-1-3] DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.HttpHandler - 

Request DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: EmptyByteBufBE)
GET /json/version HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: selenium/4.0.0 (java windows)
host: localhost:63134
accept: */*

Response DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 424
```

I need to find a way to remove the debug message during execution , this occur on selenium 4.0

Comment: What is the solution of you problem, Is this resolved?

Comment: The issue is still present , i have tried with java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel , but still the log keep displaying

Answer (score 1):

Solution – Empty Configuration
To fix it, create an empty configuration file as logback-test.xml, and save it under $project/src/test/resources

$project/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml

Visit the below website for more reference
https://mkyong.com/logging/logback-disable-logging-in-unit-test/

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the logging level:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

to:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

or some lower level than `SEVERE`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html

Comment: Good catch....! but in documents for Info also it is saying "Typically INFO messages will be written to the console or its equivalent." may be as you suggested he needs to select another low level.

Comment: i have used  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.WARNING);  but still the debug message is still present

Comment: Then simply try lower and lower value.

Comment: i have used java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE); and java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);  but still the debug message is still present

Comment: Any solution to remove the DEBUG level logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Neet to set the logs level as ERROR/WARN/INFO.
Please use the below code in your project which is being used to run the chrome driver (End project) from where you are running.

```
((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.asynchttpclient.netty")).setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.WARN);
```